# Setting default category for display

Tags: posts, customization

The default category for the page News is news.

But I want the *page* news to show all posts.

Not just *news* posts.

All posts, includes news posts and engineering posts.

When you hit the main site is http://www.papermepress.com, it does indeed do this, as you can verify.

But when you go to News it it only shows the news category.

How do I fix so that it show both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you are understanding what a 'category page' is doing; for example your news page:

```
http://papermepress.com/?cat=1
```

this is pulling out all post with the categoy 'news' which has cat id equal to 1.

depending on your needs there are two possible things you can do.

1 - if you simply want all posts with N categories displayed without any other customisations, you need to create a menu entry link which calls both of your categories i.e. which you can test in the browser:

```
http://papermepress.com/?cat=1,7
```

2 - if you want something more complicated you will need to create a specific page and modify the loop; these might give you an idea: 
multiple categories
http://devilsworkshop.org/display-posts-multiple-categories-wordpress-page/
multiple cat with selection control
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356199/display-multiple-category-posts-on-a-page-in-wordpress

hope it helps

lorenzo